# Bidirectional sorting in gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sorting, gridview

How can I implement bi-directional sorting in the GridView, with the condition that my GridView is not bind to SQL but to datatable-column-row & dataset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your Datatable in the Viewstate when you bind it for the first time.

```
gridView1.DataBind();
ViewState["dtbl"] = YourDataTable
```

Here is the code, that allows you to do this...

```
protected void ComponentGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
DataTable dataTable = ViewState["dtbl"] as DataTable;

if (dataTable != null)
{
    DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
    dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirection(e.SortDirection);

    ComponentGridView.DataSource = dataView;
    ComponentGridView.DataBind();
}
}

private string ConvertSortDirection(SortDirection sortDirection)
{
string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

switch (sortDirection)
{
    case SortDirection.Ascending:
        newSortDirection = "ASC";
        break;

    case SortDirection.Descending:
        newSortDirection = "DESC";
        break;
}

return newSortDirection;
}
```

For details, please look at this MSDN article [GridView.Sorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the input. but the code always sort the selected column into ascending

Comment: No, it is not supporting desc. It first gets sorted to ascending and then remains ascending only.

Comment: in the code the sort direction is not being changed. it is remaining ASC Only

Comment: The GridView SortExpression always remains as "Ascending", simply add an if or an ?:-Block switching from asc to desc and vice versa, save the value into a class-variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your databinding method, you will init viewstates and then in your sorting event you will do the following like so.

```
void gvReport_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{        
    System.Data.DataTable dataTable = ViewState["dataTable"] as System.Data.DataTable;
    string sortDirection = (ViewState["sortDirection"].ToString() == "ASC" ? "DESC" : "ASC");
    ViewState["sortDirection"] = sortDirection;

    if (dataTable != null)
    {
        System.Data.DataView dataView = new System.Data.DataView(dataTable);
        dataView.Sort = String.Format("{0} {1}", e.SortExpression, sortDirection);

        gvReport.DataSource = dataView;
        gvReport.DataBind();
    }
}
```